# Идентифицирование процессора 16 бит

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Необходимо идентифицировать процессор командой cpuid,но она чёт не работает.Скажите что надо добавить к cpuid что бы вывелось например что определился проц амд?

с примерами.

```
use16
org 0x7C000
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'S'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'t'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'a'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'r'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'t'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'i'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'n'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'g'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,' '
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'M'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'o'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'u'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'s'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'e'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'O'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'S'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'.'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'.'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'.'
int 10h
 PUSH AX

   MOV AH, 0EH
   MOV AL, 0AH
   INT 10H        

   MOV AH, 0EH   
   MOV AL, 0DH     
   INT 10H        

   POP AX
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'L'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'o'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'a'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'d'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'e'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'d'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,' '
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'/'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,' '
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'i'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'n'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,' '
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'m'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'e'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'m'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'o'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'r'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'y'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,' '
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'('
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'0'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,','
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'5'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'9'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'6'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'B'
int 10h
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,')'
int 10h
 PUSH AX

   MOV AH, 0EH
   MOV AL, 0AH
   INT 10H        

   MOV AH, 0EH   
   MOV AL, 0DH     
   INT 10H        

   POP AX

cpuid
```

Comment: Из под чего запускаете? Из под винды или линукса CPUID может не работать. Сделайте хотя бы там загрузочную дискету, и из под "доса" выполняйте.

Comment: У меня 16-бит ос, тоесть это не дос система.А образ iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Гуглим CPUID

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

2. Читаем

> При EAX = 0 процессор возвращает идентификатор производителя
> процессора (англ. Vendor ID) в виде 12 символов ASCII в регистрах EBX,
> EDX, ECX (именно в таком порядке). В регистре EAX возвращается
> максимально допустимое значение EAX при вызове CPUID.
>
> Некоторые идентификаторы производителей процессоров:[1]
>
> ASCII-строка  HEX-значения EBX:EDX:ECX
>
> GenuineIntel   756E6547:49656E69:6C65746E  Intel

Как это сделать на ассемблере, на всякий случай без push, первые 4ре буквы

```
xor eax, eax; блок1   
cpuid;   
mov eax,ebx
bswap eax
mov ah,0eh;
int 10h
xor eax, eax; блок2   
cpuid;   
mov eax,ebx
bswap eax
mov al,ah    
mov ah,0eh;
int 10h
xor eax, eax; блок3   
cpuid;   
mov eax,ebx
mov al,ah    
mov ah,0eh;
int 10h
xor eax, eax; блок4
cpuid;   
mov eax,ebx
mov ah,0eh;
int 10h
```

Вторые 4-буквы пишем то же, но меняем `mov eax,ebx` на  `mov eax,edx`. Последние 4 буквы, то же, но меняем `mov eax,ebx` на  `mov eax,ecx`.
Если в порядке букв ошибся - переставьте местами блоки 1,2,3,4. Итого будет 3 по 4 блока (12 условно). Можно так же использовать стек (рекомендую pushad popad).

Обратите внимание, что в 16-битном режиме, можно пользоваться 32-битными командами, для CPUID их можно и нужно использовать (иначе вы доолго будете искать в чем секрет), `bswap eax` - команда 486 процессора, 32-битные регистры доступны из-под 386 процессора, нужно поставить соответствующие опции транслятора. `bswap eax` - меняет байты в регистре попарно и слова попарно (но вы можете применить сдвиг).

Есть ещё вариант 2, через EAX=1 http://www.sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm но там долго расписывать и гуглить все случаи возврата CPUID. Но... думаю что б отличить именно intel от именно AMD - будет более практичный вариант.

```
xor eax,eax;
inc ax;
cpuid;
mov al, ah; Поле model это биты 8..11, берем с 8-го бита т.е. второй байт.
and al, 15; оставлям 4 бита (т.е. с 8 по 11)
add al, 65 (Будет по буквам A=0 B=1 C=2 и т д до 15, через цифры сложнее)
mov ah, 0eh
int 10h
```

Для интела будут одни буквы, для АMD - другие (я так думаю, но не уверен), какие - нужно читать спецификации, поэтому 1-й метод более практичный.
The family is encoded in bits 11...8. Что писать после CPUID - не уверен, нужно вывести значение регистра AX на разных процессорах, либо внимательно перечитать кучу разных спецификаций, либо найти в сети готовые примеры с CPUID(1) - тогда этот метод возможно будет более простым. Мануалы содержат как правило устаревшую информацию о процессорах 10-летней давности (у меня уже ни одно такого рабочего нету).

Для развития можно почитать тут http://habr.com/ru/company/intel/blog/220851/